# Only select rows, not header from a table in html

Tags: html, autohotkey

I am trying to scrape a table from a website and my final output has to be the tabular data from **the first column**.

The table is structured as in the picture below:

[image]

The rows that I'm interested in are located under the classes `row` and `alt`.
Running the code below also gets three unwanted cells, one from the first row `align = "right"`, one from the second row `class="gna"` and one from the last row, which is configured exactly like the first row - `align = "right"`.

```
wb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
wb.Visible := True
wb.Navigate("C:\Users\Marian\Downloads\webpage.htm")
; Wait for page to load:
While wb.Busy or wb.ReadyState != 4
    Sleep, 100

Table := wb.document.getElementById("gvSearchResults")
Rows := Table.rows
Loop % rows.length 
{
    cells := rows[A_Index-1].cells

        out .= cells["0"].innerText ","

    out := RTrim(out,",") "`n"
}
Msgbox, %out%
```

How can I put more filters to the output, in order to limit the results only to the wanted cells? Thank you!

LE: I think that `getElementsbyClassname` and `queryselectorall()` are not working because the html protocol for this webpage does not support them.

The html code begins with:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<!-- saved from url=(0021)http://www.google.com -->  ;This was adapted according to the comment section
<HTML><HEAD><META content="IE=7.0000" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<TITLE>ECSD |>> Files</TITLE>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `querySelectorAll` to get all the `.row` and `.alt` rows.
After that you can just skip the last row in the loop

```
rows := wb.document.querySelectorAll("#gvSearchResults tr.row, #gvSearchResults tr.alt")
Loop % rows.length - 1   ;-1 added to skip the last row 
{
    cells := rows[A_Index-1].cells

        out .= cells["0"].innerText ","

    out := RTrim(out,",") "`n"
}
Msgbox, %out%
```

---

**Edit** based on the comments.
The page in question has the `<META content="IE=7.0000" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">` tag that forces IE to run in IE7 compatibility mode. IE7 doesn't support `querySelectorAll`.

This solution also works while IE is running in IE7 mode. It is not very flexible since you must know which rows need to be skipped beforehand.

```
wb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
wb.Visible := True
wb.Navigate("C:\Users\Marian\Downloads\webpage.htm")
; Wait for page to load:
While wb.Busy or wb.ReadyState != 4
    Sleep, 100

Table := wb.document.getElementById("gvSearchResults")
Rows := Table.rows
Loop % rows.length - 1 ;-1 added to skip the last row
{
   if (A_index = 1 OR A_index = 2) ;skip the first and the second iteration of the loop, effectively skipping the first and the second row of the table;
   continue   

   cells := rows[A_Index-1].cells
   out .= cells["0"].innerText ","
   out := RTrim(out,",") "`n"
}
Msgbox, %out%
```

Comment: To simplify, this is the only table in the page. I'm not familiar with `Document` method `QuerySelector()` and I'm getting `unknown name` error when trying your code. T

Comment: Also, when I said that the last row is configured as the first, I was reffering to the first row that has  `allign = "right"`

Comment: I just got a chance to test the code, works fine with IE11 and a mock-up table. Can you please show me how do you declare `wb`.

Comment: Check out the updated question, with all the edits. Thank you!

Comment: First check this http://prntscr.com/nq5svy and this https://superuser.com/questions/149068/how-to-add-a-local-file-to-trusted-zone-in-ie8

Comment: @MarianV. add this at the start of webpagehtml `<!-- saved from url=(0021)http://www.google.com -->`

Comment: I've modified the html for testing purposes only as you suggested and I also have modified the security settings to allow active content to run from computer. You can see in the updated question the first part of the html code. Could the problem be that it states Internet Explorer 7 which doesn't support `QuerrySelectorAll()`? Also, it's worth mentioning that the code will be used directly on a intranet webpage, I saved it locally only to test the code at home. Thank you again for your effort.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193553/discussion-between-yane-and-marian-v).